# ¿Cómo incluir documentos HTML en otro HTML?

Tags: html, css, html5, iframe

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con HTML CSS y JS.

Me preguntaba si es es recomendable tener unos archivos en la carpeta donde tengo todo el html que sea "header.html" o "footer.html" y incluirlo donde yo quiera y así no tener que reescribirlo otra vez.

Si la respuesta es que sí, entonces ¿cómo lo incluyo en otro documento de html como puede ser "index.html" por ejemplo?

He buscado por internet y he encontrado que la gente usa los iFrames(que parecen obsoletos), y  sin embargo ninguna parece ayudarme demasiado, ¿alguna recomendación?

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en recomendaciones terminan cerradas por que no se ajustan a [ask], recomiendo leer también [tour], una vez hecho si te es posible editar para mejorar tu publicación adelante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con una función de js y un div al que asignes la función, en ese div vas a cargar el menú con js, básicamente el html sería un div como este:

```
<div id="incluir-header"></div>
```

Y la función de js sería algo como esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Ponemos todo el contenido del header en el contenedor llamado "incluir-header" (o como quieras llamarlo) a través del html de JS
$("#incluir-header").html('<div id="header"><ul><li id="inicio">Inicio</li><li id="pagina1">Página 1</li><li id="pagina2">Página 2</li><li id="pagina3">Página 3</li><li id="pagina4">Página 4</li></ul></div>');

    //Comprobamos la URL, por ejemplo, para el index:
if (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "")
{  $("#inicio").addClass('activo'); };

if (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "index")
{  $("#inicio").addClass('activo'); };

if (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "index.html")
{  $("#inicio").addClass('activo'); };

    //Y así con todas las páginas y sus URLs variantes (que terminan con .html o .php por si acceden desde ese enlace)

    //Página 1
if (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "pagina1")
{  $("#pagina1").addClass('activo'); };

if (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "pagina1.php")
{  $("#pagina1").addClass('activo'); };

    //Página 2
if (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "pagina2")
{  $("#pagina2").addClass('activo'); };

if (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "pagina2.php")
{  $("#pagina2").addClass('activo'); };

    //Página 3
if (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "pagina3")
{  $("#pagina3").addClass('activo'); };

if (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "pagina3.html")
{  $("#pagina3").addClass('activo'); };

    //Página 4
if (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "pagina4")
{  $("#pagina4").addClass('activo'); };

if (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) == "pagina4.html")
{  $("#pagina4").addClass('activo'); };

});
```

Algo de css para dejarlo bonito

```
/* Estilos de ejemplo */

#header {
    max-width:900px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    background:#CCC;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

li {
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    background:#666;
    padding:15px;
}

li:hover {
    color:#666;
    background:white;
}

.activo {
    color:#666;
    background:white;
    border:1px red solid;
}
```

Y ya estaría, si esto no te convence solo tendrías que hacerlo con php y sería:

```
<?php include("ruta/de/tu/header.html"); ?>
```

Espero haberte ayudado, yo te recomendaría el php ya que es mas sencillo y mas facil, espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo sería hacerlo como dice el compañero, con php, el código es muy sencillo y te va a ahorrar mucho tiempo en el diseño de tus paginas.

```
<?php include("ruta/de/tu/header.html"); ?>
```

Puedes crear varios documentos html con sus reglas de css y añadirlos facilmente.